# C# equivalent of Get-SPServiceApplicationPool

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, service-application, application-pool

How to I get a list of all `SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool` on my current farm?
There is a powershell command that can do this named `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool` but I want to get the list in a C# application without using a PowerShell object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following: You can modify according to your need and name any service which is by default present in Each webaplication.

```
foreach (SPService service in SPFarm.Local.Services)
{
    if (service.Name.Equals("ServiceName"))
    {
        foreach (SPServiceApplication serviceApp in service.Applications)
        {
            SPIisWebServiceApplication webServiceApp = (SPIisWebServiceApplication) serviceApp;
            SPIisWebServiceApplicationPool appPool = webServiceApp.ApplicationPool;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it gets all the used application pools. I need all the avalible appolication pools.

Comment: You mean all application pools that sharepoint sites are not using? Or somthing else?

Comment: I need a list of all the application pools available to create a new Service Application. For example when you create a new service application you can select use existing application pool. I need all the pools from that combobox. The exact list that `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool` returns without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace AppPoolEnum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryEntries appPools = 
                new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools").Children;

            foreach (DirectoryEntry appPool in appPools)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(appPool.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400464/enumerating-application-pools-in-iis

Comment: This dosent work. There are some pools that are displayed in Sharepoint but are not displayed in IIS (or using your code).